# build error : Error: Your ios platform does not have Api.js

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm create a my new application ionic1 and platform ios. i'hve build ios is get a error [image]

```
ionic info.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your platform

```
 cordova platform update ios
```

Comment: now run it command : **ionic platform update ios**                           `Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (updatePlatform is not callable from the iOS project API, you will need to do this manually.)`